# jQuery bxslider not showing all images

Tags: jquery, bxslider

The slider is only showing the first image:

http://jsfiddle.net/7HKXH/

```
<div id="bxslider">
    <img alt="" title="" src="http://interior-design-ideas.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/1400327585.png" />
    <img alt="" title="" src="http://interior-design-ideas.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2527547172_575ec12b3f_z1.jpg" />
    <img alt="" title="" src="http://interior-design-ideas.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/3992311797_e86e2343e01.jpg" />
</div>


    $("#bxslider").bxSlider({
        mode: 'slide',
        responsive: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any `mode:'slide'` delete that and it will work.

Mode has 'horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade', see all available options here: http://bxslider.com/options

Also responsive option is not needed cause true is the default option.

Comment: No problems, be sure to check the examples, it has some interesting examples to create.